# MIgrating From Arduino Nano to ESP32

Tags: arduino, esp32

I have an application that uses pin 2, 3, and 5 on Arduino Nano. I want to migrate from Nano to ESP32. My ESP32 was Wemos R32 and I connect the app to pin GPIO 25, 26, and 17. However I was not able to get the reading result. Is there something wrong with my code ([from here](https://www.instructables.com/Interfacing-a-Digital-Micrometer-to-a-Microcontrol/))?

```
int req = 17; //mic REQ line goes to pin 5 through q1 (arduino high pulls request line low)
int dat = 25; //mic Data line goes to pin 2
int clk = 26; //mic Clock line goes to pin 3
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;
int signCh = 8;
int sign = 0;
int decimal;
float dpp;
int units;

byte mydata[14];
String value_str;
long value_int; //was an int, could not measure over 32mm
float value;

void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600);

pinMode(req, OUTPUT);

pinMode(clk, INPUT_PULLUP);

pinMode(dat, INPUT_PULLUP);

digitalWrite(req,LOW); // set request at high

}

void loop() {

digitalWrite(req, HIGH); // generate set request
for( i = 0; i < 13; i++ ) {
k = 0;
for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
while( digitalRead(clk) == LOW) {
} // hold until clock is high
while( digitalRead(clk) == HIGH) {
} // hold until clock is low
bitWrite(k, j, (digitalRead(dat) & 0x1));
}

mydata[i] = k;

}
sign = mydata[4];
value_str = String(mydata[5]) + String(mydata[6]) + String(mydata[7]) + String(mydata[8] + String(mydata[9] + String(mydata[10]))) ;
decimal = mydata[11];
units = mydata[12];

value_int = value_str.toInt();
if (decimal == 0) dpp = 1.0;
if (decimal == 1) dpp = 10.0;
if (decimal == 2) dpp = 100.0;
if (decimal == 3) dpp = 1000.0;
if (decimal == 4) dpp = 10000.0;
if (decimal == 5) dpp = 100000.0;

value = value_int / dpp;

if (sign == 0) {
Serial.println(value,decimal);
}
if (sign == 8) {
Serial.print("-"); Serial.println(value,decimal);
}

digitalWrite(req,LOW);
delay(100);
}
```

I am reading from Mitutoyo Digimatic measurement device. I want to be able to read the measurement from PC. I want to use BLE as my communication channel so I try to migrate from Arduino Nano to ESP32. However there is no reading at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but I think it is a voltage level problem. The ESP works in 3.3V and if I look at the specifications of the digimatic interface I see that it takes at least 4.2V input.

[image]

you may have to interface I/O for 3v3 <> 5V compatibility. Also have a look to interface speed (I don't find information) as The clock frequency of ESP32 is 15 times faster than that of the Arduino Uno...